Pre-populate existing string in input field using Angular 17
My .TS code:
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ipd.name = 'John Doe';

and x.component.html:
{{reg.name}} /
<input type="text" id="client" [(ngModel)]="ipd.name">

The output shows that it populates John Doe correctly as shown below and also notice {{reg.name}} displaying John Doe:

Having said that, I want the input field to populate dynamically from {{reg.name}}. I tried this in my .TS but it's not working:
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ipd.name = this.reg.name;


Please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated! stackblitz

I dont understand your question or what issue your having. What is reg what is idp how is the value from idp supposed to be transfered to reg

@VincentMenzel I have rephrase my question. Please have a look.

@NarenMurali Thank you for the comment. I don't know how to replicate it as the data {{reg.item}} comes from JSON file. I have rephrased my question for easier understandability. Please have a look.

you'll probably want to change that value from inside a subscription... (the one that retrieves this.reg.name)   But maybe include your requirements or more about what the purpose is... is this a default value? should it accept user-input?  does it override... in a broader sense why are you needing to assign it's value based on the other.  It'll help if you include more code, too... couldn't hurt to include the full component's .ts file in your question.

@browsermator: You are right. Adding it inside the subscription solved the problem. Thank you so much.
The 2nd form is to be submitted to another department. However, the old data population is required but the old data may not be relevant after x months. Hence, pre-population is required but can't use the old data for all cases.
